# Confused about ownership in situations involving lines and map

Tags: rust, ownership

```
fn problem() -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let my_string = String::from("First Line\nSecond Line");
    my_string.lines().collect()
}
```

This fails with the compilation error:

```
  |
7 |     my_string.lines().collect()
  |     ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |     |
  |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
  |     `my_string` is borrowed here
```

I understand what this error means - it's to stop you returning a reference to a value which has gone out of scope. Having looked at the type signatures of the functions involved, it appears that the problem is with the [lines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.lines) method, which borrows the string it's called on. But why does this matter? I'm iterating over the lines of the string in order to get a vector of the parts, and what I'm returning is this "new" vector, not anything that would (illegally) directly reference `my_string`.

(I'm aware I could fix this particular example very easily by just using the string literal rather than converting to an "owned" string with `String::from`. This is a toy example to reproduce the problem - in my "real" code the string variable is read from a file, so I obviously can't use a literal.)

What's even more mysterious to me is that the following variation on the function, which to me ought to suffer from the same problem, works fine:

```
fn this_is_ok() -> Vec<i32> {
    let my_string = String::from("1\n2\n3\n4");
    my_string.lines().map(|n| n.parse().unwrap()).collect()
}
```

The reason can't be `map` doing some magic, because this also fails:

```
fn also_fails() -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let my_string = String::from("First Line\nSecond Line");
    my_string.lines().map(|s| s).collect()
}
```

I've been playing about for quite a while, trying various different functions inside the `map` - and some pass and some fail, and I've honestly no idea what the difference is. And all this is making me realise that I have very little handle on how Rust's ownership/borrowing rules work in non-trivial cases, even though I thought I at least understood the basics. So if someone could give me a relatively clear and comprehensive guide to what is going on in all these examples, and how it might be possible to fix those which fail, in some straightforward way, I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is in the type of the value yielded by `lines`: `&str`. In order to avoid unnecessary clones, `lines` actually returns references to slices of the string it's called on, and when you collect it to a `Vec`, that `Vec`'s elements are simply references to slices of your string. So, of course when your function exits and the string is dropped, the references inside the `Vec` will be dropped and invalid. Remember, `&str` is a borrowed string, and `String` is an owned string.

The parsing works because you take those `&str`s then you read them into an `i32`, so the data is transferred to a new value and you no longer need a reference to the original string.

To fix your problem, simply use `str::to_owned` to convert each element into a `String`:

```rust
fn problem() -> Vec<String> {
    let my_string = String::from("First Line\nSecond Line");
    my_string.lines().map(|v| v.to_owned()).collect()
}
```

It should be noted that `to_string` also works, and that `to_owned` is actually part of the [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) trait, so it is useful for other borrowed types as well.

For references to sized values (`str` is unsized so this doesn't apply), such as an `Iterator<Item = &i32>`, you can simply use [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) to clone every element so they are no longer references.

An alternative solution would be to take the `String` as an argument so it, and therefore references to it, can live past the scope of the function:

```rust
fn problem(my_string: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    my_string.lines().collect()
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense, and indeed I'd been messing around with `.to_owned` to try to fix things before, without being able to get it to work. I have now, although several of my other functions all had to be converted from taking `&str` slices to taking owned `String`s. I suppose that's inevitable (I now see I misunderstood [part](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices-as-parameters) of the Rust book, I thought it was saying that taking string slices was always preferred, but I now see that's only in favour of borrowed `String`s, not owned ones). Thanks again.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I actually realize a bit of a mistake in my second sample and I've changed it from `&String` to `&str`, since `&str` is more general.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that this line:

```
let my_string = String::from("First Line\nSecond Line");
```

copies the string data to a buffer allocated on the heap (so no longer `'static`). Then `lines` returns references to that heap-allocated buffer.

Note that [`&str` also implements a `lines` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines), so you don't need to copy the string data to the heap, you can use your string directly:

```
fn problem() -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let my_string = "First Line\nSecond Line";
    my_string.lines().collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=04a92984206caccb25812837be32ab47)

which avoids all unnecessary allocations and copying.

Comment: Thanks, but as I already said in my question - I'm aware I could fix the example like this, but in my real situation the string is dynamic, not a literal so I can't do this. Using `to_owned`, as suggested in the other answer, and altering the other functions which use the output of this, fixed it for me.